# How to get C++ MFC Control HANDLE by it's id?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have for example IDC_EDIT1 C++ MFC Controls , How Can I get its handle ?
By which Windows API , Can I done it ?

Answer (score 5):

`CWnd`-derived objects have a `GetSafeHwnd` member function to retrieve the Windows handle of that object, so if your control is in a dialog you can retrieve the handle like this:

```
HWND hwnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1).GetSafeHwnd();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a handle to a control by calling the Windows API function [GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481.aspx):

> Retrieves a handle to a control in the specified dialog box.

The [CWnd::GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw.aspx) class member of the `CWnd` class also has an overload to retrieve a control's handle:

```
HWND hWnd = NULL;
someWnd->GetDlgItem( IDC_EDIT1, &hWnd );
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to throw my two cents in, too.

- Since you are in MFC world, you might be better off with the pointer
  to CWnd than with the raw HWND. In that case, use `pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)`.
- Take it one step further and create a
  "control variable" for your    IDC_EDIT1 using Class Wizard. That way
  you would have a class member    variable associated with that edit
  control, and you would not need to    get its handle.